# Javascript change DIV colour when scrolling down

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, colors

I have this code and it doesn't change the div's color. I have tried a lot of scripts from stackoverflow but I can't find one that works.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 20) {
    document.getElementById("scroller").style.background = "#3C3F47";
  }
});
```

```css
#scroller {
  height: 80px;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // ie8
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); // ie5-7
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;         // netscape
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;       // Safari 1.x
  opacity: 0.5;              // Good browsers
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroller" class="navbar-fixed-top scroller">
  asd
</div>
```

Comment: you have scrollTop = 0 always since you dont have a scroll bar. Try a CSS height: 200% on body to have a scrollBar and then scroll

Comment: your code works fine, I think your problem is that you haven't used `$(document).ready()` at the beginning of your jquery code

Comment: The snippet would work if it would have had a scrollbar and if it would have specified jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(window) works whene jquery is loaded !

It seems you didn't load any jquery file

> 1.Download jquery from this url and load it on your page !

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/

> 2.Do like this :

```
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 20) {
    document.getElementById("scroller").style.background = "#3C3F47";
  }
});
})
```